# Get Hubot to talk at a certain time?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, hubot

I'm thinking about making a Hubot clock-based notifier (think "It's 5, time to go home!" but less annoying and for a different reason).  What's the best way to go about doing something like this in a Hubot script?

[**edit**] Here's an example using node-cron:

```
TIMEZONE = "America/New_York"
QUITTING_TIME = '0 0 17 * * 2-6' # M-F 5pm
ROOM = "Dev"

cronJob = require('cron').CronJob

module.exports = (robot) ->
        gohome = new cronJob QUITTING_TIME,
                ->
                        robot.messageRoom ROOM, "It's 5!  Go home!"
                null
                true
                TIMEZONE
```

dependencies:

```
"cron": "0.3.3",
"time": "0.8.2"
```

Comment: does this code make cronJob run automatically when Hubot launches?

Comment: @Hlung yes, when the script is loaded.

Comment: I had weird problems with messageRoom not working in the cron job callback. I ended up using robot.send.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would use node-cron.  It's pretty flexible and fits your use case well.

> https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron

Answer (score 7):

I just stumbled upon [hubot-cron](https://github.com/miyagawa/hubot-cron).

This lets you schedule messages in hubot, but unfortunately doesn't persist jobs through restarts.

Comment: Hi, I wrote hubot-cron. It saves your jobs in `robot.brain` which means it persists data through restarts as long as you use persistent data store such as Redis.